# Vue.js how to achieve requested Grid view

Tags: vue.js, layout, vuetify.js

I'm struggling with creating wanted grid system in Vue.
I need to create something like this.

[image: Wanted layout]

And here is picture of what I can create.

[image: Created layout]

As you can see, my layout is starting from middle and also I don't know how to add that History component to be under two cards but next to another.

Here is my code:

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 md3 lg3 >
          <Communication class="ml-6 mr-6" />
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 md5 lg5>
          <ActiveCall class="mr-2" />
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 md4 lg4>
          <Contacts class="ml-4 mr-6" />
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

I hope I provided everything needed.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try/modify this approach:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex lg9>
          <v-flex lg4>
            <Communication />
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex lg8>
            <ActiveCall />
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex lg12>
            <History />
          </v-flex>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex lg3>
          <Contacts />
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>;
```

Comment: I tried to use what you suggested it is not working well. [image](https://imgur.com/a/I3janv5)